# Sheets("sheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(k, 27)).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone

Tags: excel, vba

I get an "application-defined or object-defined error" remark on the following line when I want to select a range of cells:

```
Sheets("sheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(k, 27)).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
```

Why does that not work, but the following line does?

```
Sheets("sheet").Activate
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(k, 27)).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
```

or this line also works:

```
Sheets("sheet").Cells(1,1).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
```

*editted for more clearance*

Comment: Looks like your sheet `sheet` might not be activated in the first example. However, please not that you normally don't need to select a range - see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)!

Comment: I tried the activate to see if that was a solution and it appeared to be so, but earlier in the code i also do: "Sheets("sheet").Cells(k + 1, 1).Value = tags(k).tagname" without activating the sheet. Why does that work then?

Comment: The selecting was just an example. I could do anything on the fields directly, ie. changing the font

Comment: the `.Select` method requires you to have the sheet activated. You can manipulate values on the sheet without activating it - but to Select anything from the sheet it needs to be active/selected.

Comment: Working with ranges does not required the sheet to be active. however, a selection can only be - by definition - on the active sheet, therefore you run into the error.

Comment: the actual line that fails is: "Sheets("sheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(k, 27)).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone

Comment: I will edit this in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off.  Give this a try:

```
Range(Sheets("sheet").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("sheet").Cells(k, 27)).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
```